# keep white spaces as it is in html o/p

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting text from rich text box

For exmaple : "abc    def" .

I am supposed to show a drop down box at those white spaces but browsers are eleminating tose white spaces automatically.

I have tried this code :

```
var text = div.innerHTML;    
var regex = new RegExp(" ", "g");  
text = text.replace(regex, " &nbsp; ");  
div.innerHTML = text;  '
```

this keeps the proper alignment with 2 extra spaces

Is there any way so that I can replace blank space by `&nbsp;` in text but if text comes betwwen the tags ex. `<font size="10"` then space between font and size will not be replaced

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Set the style of the div to

```
white-space: pre;
```

and you don't have to do all the mess with javascript.

Comment: hey I am getting another issue because of this .. I have a div inside which I have some text separated by enter keys. white-space:pre works fine for single liner text but it creates enters <br> tags and shows big spaces between two sentences so some text is getting cut. Is there any solution for it?

Answer (score 0):

use `&nbsp;&nbsp;` for double space. Browsers will eliminate extra space by default.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a pre tag in html `"<pre>string</pre>"`
or make a css class like the pre :

```
.wspaces{
    white-space: pre;
    white-space: pre-wrap;       /* css-3 */
    white-space: -moz-pre-wrap;  /* Mozilla, since 1999 */
    white-space: -pre-wrap;      /* Opera 4-6 */
    white-space: -o-pre-wrap;    /* Opera 7 */
    word-wrap: break-word;       /* Internet Explorer 5.5+ */
}
```